# Scala: List[Future] to Future[List] disregarding failed futures

Tags: scala, future

I'm looking for a way to convert an arbitrary length list of Futures to a Future of List. I'm using Playframework, so ultimately, what I really want is a `Future[Result]`, but to make things simpler, let's just say `Future[List[Int]]` The normal way to do this would be to use `Future.sequence(...)` but there's a twist... The list I'm given usually has around 10-20 futures in it, and it's not uncommon for one of those futures to fail (they are making external web service requests).

Instead of having to retry all of them in the event that one of them fails, I'd like to be able to get at the ones that succeeded and return those.

For example, doing the following doesn't work:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure

val listOfFutures = Future.successful(1) :: Future.failed(new Exception("Failure")) :: 
                    Future.successful(3) :: Nil

val futureOfList = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)

futureOfList onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println("Success!!! " + x)
  case Failure(ex) => println("Failed !!! " + ex)
}

scala> Failed !!! java.lang.Exception: Failure
```

Instead of getting the only the exception, I'd like to be able to pull the 1 and 3 out of there. I tried using `Future.fold`, but that apparently just calls `Future.sequence` behind the scenes.

Comment: If you are using Twitter's `Future`, it has a method called `collectToTry` with that you just need to filter the successful ones
https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future$.html#collectToTry[A](fs:scala.collection.Seq[com.twitter.util.Future[A]]):com.twitter.util.Future[Seq[com.twitter.util.Try[A]]]

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The trick is to first make sure that none of the futures has failed.  `.recover` is your friend here, you can combine it with `map` to convert all the `Future[T]` results to `Future[Try[T]]]` instances, all of which are certain to be successful futures.

*note: You can use `Option` or `Either` as well here, but `Try` is the cleanest way if you specifically want to trap exceptions*

```
def futureToFutureTry[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] =
  f.map(Success(_)).recover { case x => Failure(x)}

val listOfFutures = ...
val listOfFutureTrys = listOfFutures.map(futureToFutureTry(_))
```

Then use `Future.sequence` as before, to give you a `Future[List[Try[T]]]`

```
val futureListOfTrys = Future.sequence(listOfFutureTrys)
```

Then filter:

```
val futureListOfSuccesses = futureListOfTrys.map(_.filter(_.isSuccess))
```

You can even pull out the specific failures, if you need them:

```
val futureListOfFailures = futureListOfTrys.map(_.filter(_.isFailure))
```

Comment: Thanks! `.recover` was indeed the missing piece for me.

Comment: You could use `_.collect{ case Success(x) => x}` instead of `_.filter(_.isSuccess)` to get rid of `Try` in type of `futureListOfSuccesses`.

Comment: In scala 2010 `.recover(x => Failure(x))` is not valid, use `.recover({case e => Failure(e)})` instead

Comment: I think you're missing the future wrapper:

  def futureToFutureOfTry[A](f: Future[A]): Future[Try[A]] = {
    val p = Promise[Try[A]]()
    f.map{ a=>
      p.success(scala.util.Success(a))
    }.recover{
      case x: Throwable =>
        p.success(Failure(x))
    }
    p.future
  }

Comment: not so. I'm mapping a Future to another future, an intervening Promise isn't needed and would be wasteful

Comment: Great answer.  I found that my version of scala gave me an error on the line >   f.map(Success(_)).recover(x => Failure(x)).      I corrected the error, and wrote a few tests so i could better understand the solution.  I have included the code in an additional answer, below.

Comment: Note that if you're using Finagle futures (`com.twitter.util.Future`), then it's `Future.collect(listOfFutures)` which returns a future of a sequence.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I need this exact thing. Not only are you good at slides you are ok at scala. Ha ha

Comment: This is gold. I wonder if there is an easy way to use `Seq.partition` to separate successes from failures.

Comment: There is no need to wrap the Futures into anything. Just use `.transformWith` to handle `Success` and `Failure` directly. You still may want to wrap the results into an `Option` and then collect the `Some`s but it is still a whole lot more readable then this `listOfFutureTrys`.

Answer (score 19):

Scala 2.12 has an improvement on `Future.transform` that lends itself in an anwser with less codes.

```
val futures = Seq(Future{1},Future{throw new Exception})

// instead of `map` and `recover`, use `transform`
val seq = Future.sequence(futures.map(_.transform(Success(_)))) 

val successes = seq.map(_.collect{case Success(x)=>x})
successes
//res1: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future(Success(List(1)))

val failures = seq.map(_.collect{case Failure(x)=>x})
failures
//res2: Future[Seq[Throwable]] = Future(Success(List(java.lang.Exception)))
```

Answer (score 11):

I tried Kevin's answer, and I ran into a glitch on my version of Scala (2.11.5)...  I corrected that, and wrote a few additional tests if anyone is interested... here is my version >

```
implicit class FutureCompanionOps(val f: Future.type) extends AnyVal {

    /** Given a list of futures `fs`, returns the future holding the list of Try's of the futures from `fs`.
      * The returned future is completed only once all of the futures in `fs` have been completed.
      */
    def allAsTrys[T](fItems: /* future items */ List[Future[T]]): Future[List[Try[T]]] = {
      val listOfFutureTrys: List[Future[Try[T]]] = fItems.map(futureToFutureTry)
      Future.sequence(listOfFutureTrys)
    }

    def futureToFutureTry[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] = {
      f.map(Success(_)) .recover({case x => Failure(x)})
    }

    def allFailedAsTrys[T](fItems: /* future items */ List[Future[T]]): Future[List[Try[T]]] = {
      allAsTrys(fItems).map(_.filter(_.isFailure))
    }

    def allSucceededAsTrys[T](fItems: /* future items */ List[Future[T]]): Future[List[Try[T]]] = {
      allAsTrys(fItems).map(_.filter(_.isSuccess))
    }
}


// Tests... 



  // allAsTrys tests
  //
  test("futureToFutureTry returns Success if no exception") {
    val future =  Future.futureToFutureTry(Future{"mouse"})
    Thread.sleep(0, 100)
    val futureValue = future.value
    assert(futureValue == Some(Success(Success("mouse"))))
  }
  test("futureToFutureTry returns Failure if exception thrown") {
    val future =  Future.futureToFutureTry(Future{throw new IllegalStateException("bad news")})
    Thread.sleep(5)            // need to sleep a LOT longer to get Exception from failure case... interesting.....
    val futureValue = future.value

    assertResult(true) {
      futureValue match {
        case Some(Success(Failure(error: IllegalStateException)))  => true
      }
    }
  }
  test("Future.allAsTrys returns Nil given Nil list as input") {
    val future =  Future.allAsTrys(Nil)
    assert ( Await.result(future, 100 nanosecond).isEmpty )
  }
  test("Future.allAsTrys returns successful item even if preceded by failing item") {
    val future1 =  Future{throw new IllegalStateException("bad news")}
    var future2 = Future{"dog"}

    val futureListOfTrys =  Future.allAsTrys(List(future1,future2))
    val listOfTrys =  Await.result(futureListOfTrys, 10 milli)
    System.out.println("successItem:" + listOfTrys);

    assert(listOfTrys(0).failed.get.getMessage.contains("bad news"))
    assert(listOfTrys(1) == Success("dog"))
  }
  test("Future.allAsTrys returns successful item even if followed by failing item") {
    var future1 = Future{"dog"}
    val future2 =  Future{throw new IllegalStateException("bad news")}

    val futureListOfTrys =  Future.allAsTrys(List(future1,future2))
    val listOfTrys =  Await.result(futureListOfTrys,  10 milli)
    System.out.println("successItem:" + listOfTrys);

    assert(listOfTrys(1).failed.get.getMessage.contains("bad news"))
    assert(listOfTrys(0) == Success("dog"))
  }
  test("Future.allFailedAsTrys returns the failed item and only that item") {
    var future1 = Future{"dog"}
    val future2 =  Future{throw new IllegalStateException("bad news")}

    val futureListOfTrys =  Future.allFailedAsTrys(List(future1,future2))
    val listOfTrys =  Await.result(futureListOfTrys,  10 milli)
    assert(listOfTrys(0).failed.get.getMessage.contains("bad news"))
    assert(listOfTrys.size == 1)
  }
  test("Future.allSucceededAsTrys returns the succeeded item and only that item") {
    var future1 = Future{"dog"}
    val future2 =  Future{throw new IllegalStateException("bad news")}

    val futureListOfTrys =  Future.allSucceededAsTrys(List(future1,future2))
    val listOfTrys =  Await.result(futureListOfTrys,  10 milli)
    assert(listOfTrys(0) == Success("dog"))
    assert(listOfTrys.size == 1)
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this question and have another solution to offer:

```
def allSuccessful[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[Future[A]])
                                                (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]], A, M[A]], 
                                                 executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]] = {
    in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) {
      (fr, fa) ⇒ (for (r ← fr; a ← fa) yield r += a) fallbackTo fr
    } map (_.result())
}
```

The idea here is that within the fold you are waiting for the next element in the list to complete (using the for-comprehension syntax) and if the next one fails you just fallback to what you already have.

Comment: I dislike the name but I like the way it's done, straight from the sequence impl

Answer (score 1):

You can easily wraps future result with option and then flatten the list:

```
def futureToFutureOption[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Option[T]] =
    f.map(Some(_)).recover {
      case e => None
    }
val listOfFutureOptions = listOfFutures.map(futureToFutureOption(_))

val futureListOfOptions = Future.sequence(listOfFutureOptions)

val futureListOfSuccesses = futureListOfOptions.flatten
```

Comment: Just in case someone else encounters an error with Some in the first function, the first function can be rewritten like so to prevent compiler error:
def futureToFutureOption[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Option[T]] =
    f.map(Option(_)).recover {
      case e => None
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can also collect successful and unsuccessful results in different lists:

```
def safeSequence[A](futures: List[Future[A]]): Future[(List[Throwable], List[A])] = {
  futures.foldLeft(Future.successful((List.empty[Throwable], List.empty[A]))) { (flist, future) =>
    flist.flatMap { case (elist, alist) =>
      future
        .map { success => (elist, alist :+ success) }
        .recover { case error: Throwable => (elist :+ error, alist) }
    }
  }
}
```