# How to go from an functor over an effect to an effect over the functor?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have two different types of users; let's call them `BasicUser` and `EnrichedUser`.

I get a value of the `Foo` user type inside a container `C` that has a `cats.Functor` instance:

```
val basicUserF: C[BasicUser] = getBasicUser(…)
```

Now I'd like to map over this value (using the functor instance) to turn the contained `BasicUser` into an `EnrichedUser` user, staying in the container:

```
import cats.syntax.all._

val enrichedUserF: C[EnrichedUser] = basicUserF.map(user => enrichUser(user))
```

However, `enrichUser` doesn't return `EnrichedUser`, but rather `OptionT[Future, EnrichedUser]`, so I end up with the following type:

```
val enrichedUserThing: C[OptionT[Future, EnrichedUser]] = …
```

How can I get from this type to `OptionT[Future, C[EnrichedUser]]` (which I'll ultimately turn into a JSON-serialized Akka HTTP response)?

Comment: Dies this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874186/scala-listfuture-to-futurelist-disregarding-failed-futures ?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure.  I can't see how Future.sequence could help me…

Comment: If you add a `Traverse` constraint to your `C`, you could use `sequence` which would do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Traverse[C]` instance you can use `sequence`.

```
scala> implicit def CTraverse: Traverse[C] = ???
CTraverse: cats.Traverse[C]

scala> def sequenced = enrichedUserThing.sequence[OptionT[Future,?], EnrichedUser]
sequenced: cats.data.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,C[EnrichedUser]]
```

Extra: If you have `-Ypartial-unification` enabled you don't need the explicit type arguments.

Comment: Okay, so I need to bite the bullet and add a Traverse instance to C :| Thanks :)